# Gender of word "Unity"

Tags: translation, grammatical-gender

I'm writing an article in Polish about game engine named "Unity". I constructed the following sentence:

Unity jest bardzo jednolita, jeśli chodzi o encje i komponenty.

This translates more or less to:

Unity is very uniform, when considering entities and components.

However, in Polish gender of nouns is somewhat more important than in English, because verbs and adjectives have different forms, depending on gender of noun they refer to. For instance, if Unity is masculine, I should write "Unity jest **jednolity**", but if feminine, "Unity jest **jednolita**". In Polish "Unity" translates directly to "jedność", which is feminine in Polish. However from what I know, I should follow the gender of noun in the original language rather than its Polish translation.

Hence finally the question: what is the gender of word "Unity"? And additionally, could you recommend some online English dictionary, which states gender of nouns?

Comment: This kind of question doesn't make sense to native English speakers. English doesn't have gender in the sense of classes that all nouns can be categorized into. I would recommend using the same strategy you would use to determine the gender of a proper noun with no etymology and some arbitrary, non-Polish form (e.g. what gender would you use for an entirely made-up game engine name like "Adadgba"? My understanding is that some languages use the gender of the corresponding common noun, so maybe go with whatever's the gender of the Polish word for "game engine").

Comment: @sumelic, Since I would still have to use *some* gender - even for made-up name, I'd probably go for "Adadgba engine" - "silnik Adadgba" and since engine is masculine, I would have my gender to work on (so to say). The problem is that "Unity" translates to proper noun with specific gender in Polish which is feminine and applying masculine forms (from "engine") to Polish-feminine "Unity" sounds kinda weird.

Comment: @sumelic, This is also interesting what you say, that there are nouns without gender specified - but then how would you say - out of my head: "Unity has specific properties. (Its/his/her) properties are: ..."? Or is this sentence invalid in terms of English grammar?

Comment: It's a question of Polish, not English. There should be some rules about the gender of loan words from other languages. For example, in German, _e-mail_ would be feminine (though some people would treat it as neuter), even though it has no gender in English. _Unity_ in German would be feminine, presumably as _-ity_  words in German end with _-heit_ and would be feminine.

Comment: You would use "it" ("its properties are..."). What I meant is that most English speakers don't think of a word/name like "Unity" as having "neuter gender" . We just use "it" because that's the pronoun that is used to refer to inanimate things in contexts like this. The use of *it/she/he* is generally based on the thing that you are referring to, not on the word that you use.

Comment: "... what is the gender of word "Unity" (in the original language)?" -- None. Neuter.

Comment: "The default assignment is the borrowing language's unmarked gender."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#Gender_in_words_borrowed_from_one_language_by_another

Comment: @Kris, Earlier rule says "The borrowed word tends to take the gender of the native word it replaces." - In this case one may object, that Unity is directly translateable to Polish "jedność", which is feminine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is well-known that inanimate things and abstract nouns in English are neuter, i.e. without gender.

Answer (score -1):

The relevant [Polish Wikipedia article](https://pl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(silnik_gry)) treats the word as a foreign proper name that doesn't show case, number, or gender.

> Gry stworzone na silniku Unity w wersji 5.1.1 obsługują 22 platformy sprzętowe, są to między innymi Windows, Linux, Android. Wśród nich znajdują się także konsole siódmej oraz ósmej generacji. Kompatybilne z Unity są również hełmy rzeczywistości wirtualnej takie jak Oculus Rift i Samsung Gear VR. Gry stworzone w Unity po zainstalowaniu wtyczki Unity Web Player mogą działać również w przeglądarce internetowej.

This seems to be the same strategy of a [Polish gaming website](https://www.gry-online.pl/S013.asp?ID=90666):

> „Unity 5 to wielki krok dla Unity, który daje twórcom możliwości tworzenia piękniejszych i bardziej skomplikowanych gier dla szerszej publiczności na wielu platformach. Chcemy by każdy miał dostęp do Unity 5 i dlatego zwiększyliśmy wartość naszych wolnych od świadczeń licencji. Unity 5 Professional zaczyna z mocą Unity 5 i dodaje do tego wartościowe narzędzia, takie jak Unity Cloud Build Pro oraz Team License. Unity 5 Personal Edition przeznaczone jest dla początkujących twórców i oferuje te same możliwości silnika i edytora za darmo”.
>   Źródło: https://www.gry-online.pl/S013.asp?ID=90666

Comment: So? What's the answer, then?

Comment: This is not entirely true, that Wikipedia article treats Unity as name, adding "engine" ("silnik Unity"), which dictates masculine gender. This is a way to somewhat escape problem of Unity's gender, but one should add "engine" to Unity every time grammar dictates usage of gender-aware verb or adjective. This is of course doable, but generates a lot of repetitions in the text.

Comment: That is the answer. The Wikipedia article doesn't mark the word morphologically, which is highly unusual for a language where even personal names are marked.

Comment: I don't speak Polish, but from what I know of Slovak and Czech, I'd expect case endings after the prepositions z and w where only _Unity_ appears.

Comment: "Unity 5 Personal Edition przeznaczone jest" suggests neutral gender here.

Comment: @Spook: Sorry I missed the predicate adjective, which has to show gender and number. My point, however, is that the word itself does not change in oblique cases (accusative, genitive, dative, instrumental), but remains as it is in English.